# Desktop Icons Huge - can't resize

Tags: icons

I was trying to rescale my ubuntu 18.04 to 150 or 125% (instead of of 100 or 200) with xrandx, display settings and unity tweak tools. Nothing would work, so I put all settings back to default, however my desktop icons stayed huge. Things I tried to get them back to normal size:

- ctrl + mouse wheel
- set icon size to 50% in nautilus
- restart
- changing the font size value in unity tweak tool

sometimes the icons disappear from my visible desktop into the edges of it. any idea on where I could have screwed up my icons?
luggie

Answer (score 0):

easy solution that did the trick:
The desktop icons were scaled huge when I changed the view to grid in nautilus.
However changing back to list view didn't change the desktop icon's view. I didnt understand that there is no list view for desktop icons.
To update them I needed to switch back to grid,  change the icon's display size and THEN change to list view again.